# Search for string between two characters if next to a specific string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am in need of some modification to my function to allow for a search of two strings on one line of a value. I am trying to work through this on my own but I need some help. Here is an example of a cell value being looked at. Assume there are no leading or trailing newlines. Also, all the cells have the same format. same number of lines, same structure of membertype: last, first etc.

[image]

Say I want to see if this cell contains a `team lead` with the name of `last2` or a `Manager` with the name `first4`. Both the type of employee and name would be user inputted.

I tried using the following that I created with the help of [this](http://regexr.com/3tjoa).

```
indexOf(':(.*):')
```

It returns the position of the content between and including the colons. Then I tried the following:

```
flatUniqArr[0].search('Supervisor:')
```

This is where I'm stuck. It returns the index to the last digit of the first line.

My thought was to do a search of the user inputted name between the colons if they follow the user inputted member type. How can I accomplish this?

Clarifications:
The end goal is to verify that the name and member type are on the same line and excluded from an array I am building for `.setHiddenValues()`. So if they are on the same line exclude from list.

Here is the function I will be adding it to:

```
var flatUniqArr = colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0].toString();})
.filter(function(e,i,a){
  return (a.indexOf(e) == i && !(visibleValueArr.some(function(f){
    return e.search(new RegExp(f,'i')) + 1;
  })));
});
return flatUniqArr;
```

Where `flatUniqArr` is the list of hidden values. `colValueArr` is the array of values from a column. `visibleValueArr` is the name which is user inputted and `memberType` will be the member type.

Attempts using Liora's solution: (Updated... Works now)

```
var flatUniqArr = []
var lines = []
Logger.log(visibleValueArr)
Logger.log(memberType)
for (var i = 0; i < colValueArr.length; i++){
  lines = colValueArr[i].toString().split('\n');
  var found = false;
  for(var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++){
    var data = lines[j].toLowerCase().split(':')
    if(data[0] == memberType.toString().toLowerCase() && data[1].indexOf(visibleValueArr.toString().toLowerCase()) != -1){
      found = true;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(found)
  if(found == false){flatUniqArr.push(colValueArr[i])} 
}

return flatUniqArr;
```

It works now. It seems like a lot of code though. I'd be open to alternative solutions if they are faster and/or less lines of code.

Updated: Added `.toString().toLowerCase()` as the user may input lowercase values.

Comment: What do you actually want? The name of the person holding a position? The Position a person of a certain name is holding?

Comment: @Luca  I've updated my question with more info. Let me know if that helps answer your question. essentially, I just want to know if it exists in that cell to ignore it from the list I'm building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume all the line have this format.

If you split each line with the separator ":"

```
var array = value.split(":")
```

Then you'd have

```
array[0] //the current role
array[1] //the list of name
array[2] //the email
```

And you can check each names then

```
if(array[0] == "Team Lead" && array[1].indexOf("last2") != -1)
```

An example with a linesplit:

```
var lines = value.toString().split("\n");
var found = false;
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length ; i++){
    var data = value.split(":")
    if(data[0] == "Team Lead" && data[1].indexOf("last2") != -1){
         found = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, all cells have the same format. All lines have the same structure.

Comment: Will that work with a cell that has multiple lines? Will it put the current role of the second line in `array[3]`?

Comment: No, you'd have to split the lines first. I'll add an example in my answer

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the quick responses. I'll be working on incorporating one of the solutions with what I already have. I'll pick an answer once I do. Thanks!

Comment: Minor typo on the word length. I couldn't edit the post myself because it's less than 6 characters.

Comment: I updated my question with something I put together. It is giving me an error. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: the error code seems pretty clear for me, but I don't see you using "setHiddenValues" anywhere

Comment: I'm using the output of `flatUniqArr`  in another function. `SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(flatUniqArr).build()`

Comment: i seems `flatUniqArr` is an object, not an array, but I can't tell you why with the current code

Comment: I've modified the code a little. I don't get an error but I do get a blank array for `flatUniqueArray`.

Comment: use `if(found == false)` instead of `if(found = false)`, elsewise it always set false to found and never enters the if

Comment: good catch. I made that change but I'm still getting empty `flatUniqueArr`. I also am getting empty `lines`.

Comment: `indexOf` was not capitalized correctly. I also changed `var lines = value.split("\n");` to `var lines = value.toString().split("\n");` It's working now. When you get a chance, update your answer and I'll mark it as my choice.

Answer (score 1):

How about just building the regex using the user input?

```
function search(line, employeeType, employeeName) {
    var regexp = '/' + employeeType + ': ' + employeeName + '/'
    return line.search(regexp)
}
```

Or better yet, if it always occurs at the beginning of the string, just use [startsWith()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp)

Comment: It doesn't always occur at the beginning of the string. All of the lines are within one cell. I may be asking for `Team Lead` which may not be the first row of the cell.

Comment: In that case, the original regex solution should be fine. From your description, the user gives both employee type and name, so we can simply search for employeeType: employeeName either in each line or using the multiline flag

Comment: yes. They provide either the first or last name. I believe your solution as is is expecting the full employeeName, correct?

Comment: Also, is there a way of incorporating it with the already included `new RegExp(f,'i')` in my code.